# Is using an if statement to redirect user away if page does not exists good practice in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router, react-router-dom

Basically, I am trying to route a user based on whether or not the page exists. So I tried to do an if statement to check the prop `profileExists`. If it is true, it would stay on the same page. Otherwise, it would reroute the user away to another route, which is the `/homepage` route. I was wondering if this is an ok thing to do in React or not. Please see code below:

```
renderWithRoot(component) {
  const { classes, profileExists, history } = this.props;

  if (profileExists === false) {
    history.push('/homepage');
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {component}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is this `renderWithRoot` function being declared and where is the `this.props` coming from? Are you effectively trying to create route protection? This *sort of* looks like you are trying to make a Higher Order Component, but it's incorrect for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok, but not quite in the way you are using it. You should either issue the redirect as an imperative navigation in a `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!profileExists) {
    history.replace('/homepage');
  }
}, [profileExists]);

...

return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    {component}
  </div>
);
```

or issue the redirect as a declarative navigation via rendering the `Redirect` component.

```
if (!profileExists) {
  return <Redirect to='/homepage' />;
}

return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    {component}
  </div>
);
```